# about columns filled with 'table' and 'value' in dimension tables queries within power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

While working on power query in power BI desktop,  as I opened each Dimension table queries, I found the right corner columns of each table have one or two columns with 'table' or 'value' as values;

Would anyone help me understand,

1. what do they indicate?
2. why are they clickable and when clicked, they are removed automatically.

[image]

Thank you for giving your valuable time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the text "Table" is what it is. In there is a table with columns and rows. By clicking on the "Expand". PowerBI will open the table and "Paste" the columns to your sheet.

It is logical when you think about it because you are looking at a dimension table.

As for the "Value" in your DimProductSubcategory, I am not 100% sure(might be j-son or xml). What you can do is click on it, it will show you what is in there, it does a drilldown. If it asks a question are you sure, press no and copy the query first so you have the original.

Comment: Thank you for responding, Aldert. How about the purpose of the text 'value'? why are they clickable?

Comment: I do not have a file to check this but I recall it is a piece of json, xml or similair. It is an expression what cannot be shown in the cell itself. I am not sure if PBI allows you to click on it. Try it!

Comment: Thanks again for your comments and response, Aldert!